# Setup RDF ontology with Virtuoso

Tags: java, rdf, jena, virtuoso

I've googled for last few hours searching for tutorials or guides about how to configure RDF store with virtuoso server (open source version).

I have RDF file which was created with Protégé software. How can I add this file to virtuoso server and configure an **end point** to be able to insert/update or querying data via Jena or other API of that kind.

Comment: in virtuoso as in most triple stores, asserting ontologies is exactly the same as asserting any other plain RDF data. See my answer below with references and pointers to do it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it might be as explain on point (16.8.3) of this [documentation page](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfinsertmethods.html) `HTTP PUT using Content-Type: application/rdf+xml`. This mechanism basically runs a `HTTP PUT` sending your file to the triple store.

`curl -T your_file.rdf entity_uri_to_store_file -u user:pass`

Think of `entity_uri_to_store_file` as if was the table where you want to save that file.

So lets say that your file is ontology1.owl and you want to save it in the entity `http://myorganisation.com/ontologies/ontology1` your command then would look like ...

`curl -T ontology1.owl http://myorganisation.com/ontologies/ontology1 -u user:pass`

Note: if you're running a Windows box you can install `curl` from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

To query the data afterwards ... you can also do it with `curl`.

`curl -F "query=YOUR SPARQL QUERY" http://your.virtuososerver.org/sparql`

Notice that you have to use [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) to access the data.

In the case of Jena, you have to use [Jena ARQ](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/), by command line ...

`java -cp ... arq.query --service 'hhttp://your.virtuososerver.org/sparql' 'SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}'`

or programatically by using the [API](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/app_api.html) ...

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryExceptionHTTP;

public class QueryTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String service = "http://your.virtuososerver.org/sparql";
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}";
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service, query);
    try {
       ResultSet results = qe.execSelect() ;
       for ( ; results.hasNext() ; ) {
           QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;
           RDFNode x = soln.get("s") ;
           RDFNode r = soln.get("p") ; 
           RDFNode l = soln.get("o") ;   
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Query error:"+e);
    } finally {
        qe.close();
    }
 }
```

Just remember to point the variable `service` to where your virtuoso server is listening.

Comment: Hello @msalvadores. Thank your for your reply. What do you mean by entity http://myorganisation.com/ontologies/ontology1? I need to own some domain on the internet to be able to publish my onthology? Can I do it on localhost?

Comment: That entity is a URI not a URL, that means that it doesn't need to be resolvable. So yo could put whatever URI you want, you don't need to own the domain.

Comment: I'm getting an erro in curl "You do not have permission to access this location." I need to configure this entity **http://myorganisation.com/ontologies/ontology1** in virtuoso?

Comment: I don't think so, what about the user and password ? are you passing them correctly ?

Comment: User and password are from default **-u dba:dba**

Comment: At this point I would email the virtuoso user mailing list ... http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users

Comment: From what I can tell from the docs, you can only upload to a WebDAV URL, no?

Answer (score 2):

From the Virtuoso Conductor (http:cname:8890/conductor) you can go to the "RDF -> RDF Store Upload" tab where you can upload RDF datasets file from file system or a URL location.

The [Virtuoso Jena Provider](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider) can be used for querying the Virtuoso Quad Store using the Jena Franework.